# scrapy returning 0 results

Tags: python, scrapy

Very new and in-experienced.
Im trying to scrape each of the Program names from this url:
https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open

When I run my scrapy program, I keep getting:

> 2018-05-15 14:26:05 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

**My Project Directory:**

```
myproject/

    scrapy.cfg           

    __init__.py

    items.py          

    pipelines.py      

    settings.py       

    spiders/         
        __init__.py
          byub.py
          F6sSpider.py
```

**My Spider File:**

```
import scrapy

class CompanySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Company"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for title in response.css('div.title'):
            yield {
                'program': title.css('div.title a.action.main.no.line::text').extract(),
            }
```

**My Log File:**

```
2018-05-15 14:20:12 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.0 started (bot: myproject)
2018-05-15 14:20:12 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.1.0, libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.4.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 18.4.0, Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr 25 2018, 14:23:58) - [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)], pyOpenSSL 17.5.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018), cryptography 2.2.2, Platform Darwin-17.5.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
2018-05-15 14:20:12 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'myproject', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'myproject.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['myproject.spiders']}
2018-05-15 14:20:12 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2018-05-15 14:20:12 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2018-05-15 14:20:12 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2018-05-15 14:20:12 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2018-05-15 14:20:12 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-05-15 14:20:12 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-05-15 14:20:12 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-05-15 14:20:13 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.f6s.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2018-05-15 14:20:13 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt: <GET https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open>
2018-05-15 14:20:13 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-05-15 14:20:13 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 1,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/scrapy.exceptions.IgnoreRequest': 1,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 220,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 560,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 15, 13, 20, 13, 614424),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'memusage/max': 49090560,
 'memusage/startup': 49090560,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 15, 13, 20, 12, 874730)}
2018-05-15 14:20:13 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Im expecting an output in my terminal to have 'Program': 'Program Name'
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting forbidden by robots.txt error, so simply add the following lines to your `settings.py`

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; rv:10.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.1 SeaMonkey/2.7.1' # any browser specific user agent will do
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False
```

Comment: okay brilliant - that seemed to work!
However, my program is not actually scraping any of the text names I want it to..


2018-05-15 16:27:54 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.f6s.com/programs?type[]=accelerator&sort=open>
{'program': []}


It's just leaving it blank, I take it there is something wrong with my spider  css?

Comment: Yeah just remove the `.` between `no.line`. It should be `div.title a.action.main.noline::text`

Comment: Please mark this answer as the correct, if it solved your question